# Inserting sp_blitz results into a temporary table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am required to execute the sp_Blitz stored procedure and report the results with priority of less 100. The procedure is returning a tone of rows but I need those with priority of 100 and less. I try to create temp table and use the INSERT INTO  EXEC approach to insert the data to the temporary table and then I can file the required data from the temp table but its failing with errors.

I follow the following steps.

```
-- created a temp table
CREATE TABLE #reports(
Priority INT,
FindingsGroup VARCHAR(100),
Finding VARCHAR (255),
DatabaseName  SYSNAME,
URL VARCHAR(255),
Details VARCHAR(MAX),
QueryPlan VARCHAR(255),
QueryPlanFiltered VARCHAR(255),
CheckID INT
);

-- tried to insert data
INSERT INTO #reports (Priority, FindingsGroup, Finding, DatabaseName, URL, Details, QueryPlan, QueryPlanFiltered, CheckId)
Exec sp_blitz
```

--get the following error stating that exec statement can not be nested. I understand that there might be procedure call or INSERT statement inside the sp_Blitz which I can not tell as I can not access the meta data of the sp_Blitz.

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.
> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Line 5

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: Use some external program liek powershell to get the data and display it. Or change the actual procedure to only return what you need

Comment: I can't change the procedure. It's part of the First Responders Kit by Brant Ozar.

Comment: Isn't it just alter procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display results with a priority of 100 or less run `sp_blitz` with this parameter:

```
exec sp_blitz @IgnorePrioritiesAbove = 100
```

If you want the results in a table, you need to create a temp table, then use the `OPENROWSET` command:

```
INSERT INTO #MyTempTable 
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',
'set fmtonly off EXEC dbo.[sp_Blitz] @OutputXMLasNVARCHAR = 1, @IgnorePrioritiesAbove = 100')
```

[sp_Blitz Documentation](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/documentation/) :

> `@IgnorePrioritiesBelow`, `@IgnorePrioritiesAbove` – if you’re not
> interested in the low-priority checks, you can pass in
> @IgnorePrioritiesAbove = 100 (or any other number). sp_Blitz®’s output
> will exclude all items with a priority > 100. If you don’t care about
> your pants being on fire, you can set @IgnorePrioritiesAbove = 50, and
> you’ll be blissfully unaware of your failing database backup jobs.

Comment: Thank you @Mitch for the quick response. I have done something lengthy and inefficient which is saving the result set into flat file then importing it to a table and filtering the results with priority less than a 100. But now I know what to do.